# viewDidLayoutSubviews: and UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to ask this question because Im utterly puzzled by the mechanics of this. I am trying to check for portrait orientation, and while it works fine in viewdidload for my case, because I only need to make the call once, I still wondered what to do if I needed to check for portrait every time the device was turned back to portrait.

I have the following code

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    self.adviceLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-25;
    [self.adviceLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-25 , 103)];
    NSLog(@"portrait");
}
```

First of all "portrait" gets loved 3 times, which I suppose is because I have 3 views inside my VC, duh. But then when I start to turn the screen around, it actually starts to log "portrait" consistently when I "turn to landscape" meaning it logs after I hit landscape mode. Is there any meaning behind this? I hate leaving a subject without understand. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for your goal:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
 // do something before rotation
}
```

or

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 // do something after rotation
}
```

`-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is called every time when view and it's subviews change their frames. This is not good practice to check orientation every time view changes it's frame.

Comment: Also you can add orientation flag to check it anywhere you want.

Comment: what do u mean by orientation flag? Regarding your answer, I cannot use these methods, because I am indeed looking to use UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait, but I don't understand why it in viewdidlayoutssubjects return true when rotating into landscape. (in other methods like viewdidload it works as intended..)

Comment: You can add boolean property for example. @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL viewOrientation. And change it in methods above.